# when does changed? flip in activerecord callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paperclip

I'm working with a Ruby on Rails application where it was authored to generate some files in the after_save callback. The paperclip gem is used in the class. When these files are created, save is called on the Ruby object which triggers a loop of this second save calling after_save which calls save which calls after_save and on and on.

save! -> after_save -> save! -> after_save!

Eventually somehow the app breaks out of this loop on its own. I'm not sure how.

My question is, if I have an attribute on a class that is changed?=true, when does *changed?* get flipped to false? We use a *changed?* check as a sort of gate to prevent this file creation from happening and it seems like changed is always true every time it enters the after_save code. I would've thought that in after_save, changed? would be false by now since the data has been saved.

Comment: after_update() can be use after you calling the after_save

Answer (score -1):

You should use `after_commit` with a condition of the key (attribute) present in the `previous_changes`.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/previous_changes